# docker web application image needs keep running

Tags: docker

I've found similar questions but didn't find the answers helpful, so I'm putting my question here. I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM websphere-liberty
COPY server.xml /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/
COPY jfpetc /opt/jfpetc/
ADD wasapp.ear /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/dropins/
ENV LICENSE accept
EXPOSE 80 9080 9448 9443 9060
```

I then build the image and try to run it with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 9080:9080 -p 9443:9443 wasapp
```

Then `docker ps` doesn't show anything running, and `docker ps -a` shows it exited. Which command can keep this web application running so I can access the login page?

Comment: If your container is exiting immediately after starting (assuming it's not supposed to do that), then it's encountering some sort of error that it can't recover from.  You should try to fix the error if you want your container to keep running.

Comment: try starting it without -d and see whats going wrong

Comment: It seems I got too many containers. Once I removed them, everything is ok. Not quite positive though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
docker run -it -d -p 9080:9080 -p 9443:9443 wasapp

Comment: This works. But the logs doesn't show the wasapp is running. It shows adminCenter is at 9080. The docker images command shows `wasapp latest              f7a12a91fb26        7 hours ago         663.7 MB docker.io/websphere-liberty   latest              62d1ef334613        5 weeks ago         513.9 MB` It seems the ear file is in the image. Also the copy lines in the Dockerfile didn't copy file and directory. Where to find the issue log? @Jachk E @jwodder @ Shibashis

Comment: can you give more details. Is it a problem in the dockerfile or is it related to the deployment of the application in the was?